# Using "make" C Programming (Learn C the Hard Way)

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I'm learning C Programming through "Learn C the Hard Way." I have am currently on Exercise 1, which can be found here: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex1.html

I understand the concept being covered, but don't understand the compiling process. While using the "make" command in the command line, why does this work:

```
$ make ex1
```

And this not work:

```
$ make ex1.c
```

I was actually just running the second command until a minute ago. I eventually figured it out though. Until I did, I kept getting this error message:

```
make: nothing to be done for 'ex1.c'
```

While this is a just a technicality, I would still like to know what's happening. Thanks :)

Comment: isn't gcc ex1.c -o ex1 ? Because gcc is the C compiler.

Comment: This question is more about the `make` program than the C language.

Comment: Sorry, will keep this in mind in all future questions. This was actually my first post on stackoverflow, and the answers have been surprisingly quick! Thank all of you guys once again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both work; they just do different tasks.

- `make ex1.c` says "using the rules in the makefile plus built-in knowledge, ensure that the file `ex1.c` is up to date".

  The `make` program finds `ex1.c` and has no rules to build it from something else (no RCS or SCCS source code, for example), so it report 'Nothing to be done'.
- `make ex1` says "using the rules in the makefile plus built-in knowledge, ensure that the file `ex1` is up to date".

  The `make` program finds that it knows a way to create an executable `ex1` from the source file `ex1.c`, so it ensures that the source file `ex1.c` is up to date (it exists, so it is up to date), and then makes sure the `ex1` is up to date too (which means 'file `ex1` was modified more recently than `ex1.c`).  If you've edited `ex1.c` since you last ran `make`, it will do the compilation to make `ex1` newer than `ex1.c`.  If the compilation fails, the file `ex1` won't exist, so you'll get another recompilation next time too.  And once it is up to date, then `make` won't rebuild `ex1` again until you modify the source again.

This is the way `make` is designed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed response. That makes sense, though coming from the python environment, this seems really rigid

Comment: I'd never seen that site before, but the title of Ex 2, "Make Is Your Python Now", is very misleading.  I get what they're trying to say, but Make is not Python.  Comparing Make and Python is like comparing a carving knife to a kitchen.  Make is specifically designed to update out-of-date files.  It's very good at that.  Python is designed to be a general purpose language.  It's very good at that.  I recommend you ignore this comparison: it seems more confusing than illuminating to me.

Answer (score 4):

The target to `make` usually specifies what you want it to build or rebuild, not what you want it to use to build something else.

If you type `ex1.c` (and there's no rule to auto-generate it), make essentially just answers "Yup, that file exists."

Answer (score 1):

the argument to the `make` tool is the name of the executable file that it
will help create for you. It should not have a `.c` extension. You should have 
written `make ex1` only.